# Selecting distinct values

Tags: postgresql, join, group-by, distinct

The domain is:

- company (id, name, adress)
- employee (id, name,  adress, company_id, expertise_id)
- dependantrelative (id, name, employee_id)
- expertise (id, name, class)

I want to know how to get the number of dependantrelatives of each employee who are unique experts in their respective companies.

The Query below does not return the correct answer. Can you help me?

```
SELECT DISTINCT dependantrelative.employee_id
      , COUNT(*) AS qty_dependantrelatives
FROM dependantrelative
INNER JOIN employee
    ON employee.id = dependantrelative.employee_id 
GROUP BY dependantrelative.employee_id
```

Comment: Please provide the DDL for your tables in the form of `CREATE TABLE` statements, sample data for each table using DML (`INSERT INTO`), and the output you want to obtain from that sample data.

Comment: You also need to involve `expertise` and `company` in the query. No wonder your query doesn't return the correct result!

Comment: The DISTINCT is useless in this case because of the GROUP BY

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I also tried to involve the expertise and company in sort of a nested query to get only the unique values but I couldn't make the join with the dependantrelative after that. How would you do that?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name yeah  :/

Answer (score 0):

I just tried out the **Query** below and it works, but I want to know if there is a faster and simple way of getting the answer.

```
SELECT employee.id
    ,COUNT(dependantrelative.employee_id) AS qty_dependantrelatives
FROM ( 
    SELECT employee.company_id
        , employee.expertise_id AS expert
        , COUNT(employee.expertise_id) 
    FROM employee
    GROUP BY employee.company_id
       , employee.expertise_id
    HAVING COUNT(employee.expertise_id)<2
) AS uniexpert
LEFT JOIN employee
    ON employee.expertise_id = uniexpert.expert
LEFT JOIN salesorderdetail
   ON dependantrelative.employee_id = employee.id
GROUP BY employee.id 
ORDER BY employee.id
```